# Button inside ListView item in Android - how to make it part of the onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, button

I am building a ListView that includes a TextView and a button.
I simply put the button so the user will know he can press the list item.
But thie forces one to either define specific OnClick listener to the button and write a lot of code or make a TextView that looks like a button but this caused the text in the button to be gray when item inside is not clicked.

Here is the resource file for the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/channelListEntry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"              
        >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

            <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/channelButton"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/search_result_button"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="   Play   "                   
            />

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Write clear, and make clear questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Just add the following to the TextView named channelButton:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

And this made the text color of the TextView (that looks like button) always black (and not only when the item is clicked).

SoftCoder: In our app, we are afraid the user will just look at the list entries and would not know there is an action to be taken when clicking the item.
So what I did is used a TextView with the shape of a button.

Answer (score 0):

To add a onClickListener to a button defined in your xml code insert the following into the activity:

```
yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YourButton);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // your code here
    }

}
```

and add to the xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/Yourbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
```

adjusting the button values as wanted

Comment: `channelButton` in the provided layout is a `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Why to add button to tell the user he can click on the list? you can already click on the listview by

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {

           // ListView Clicked item index
           int itemPosition     = position;

           // put the other code here for the item in listview


          }

     });
```

If putting the button is necessary, try to use custom listview and add as many views to the list as you like.